# Ubuntu 12.10 + Gnome 3.6: Suspend button does not work

Tags: gnome, 12.10, suspend

Clicking Suspend button from top right corner menu in Gnome desktop environment, does *nothing*. I have  Alternative Status Menu extension enabled through Tweak Tools but it seems ineffective. Is there a work-around?

Comment: sorry but this solution doesn't work, instead no more option has added at power-managment menu on settings menu. I trining to looking up and testing deb app to resolve this problem..

Answer (score 2):

It's a known bug. Looks like update is on the way. See [this bug on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1068315).

Answer (score 0):

The latest Gnome Shell includes a fix.

Ubuntu's repository is outdated, so add the Gnome repository, and run updates.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Then open the update manager and install the updates. This should fix the suspend option.